# How to read programmatically web.config values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I use asp.net and c# 4.
I have a Web.Config file

```
<globalization culture="auto:fr" uiCulture="fr"/>
```

I want to get this value in a new variable programmatically in Code Behind.

```
var test = .......
```

How to get value for culture?

**Solution Thanks to your Answers:**

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
GlobalizationSection section = (GlobalizationSection)config.GetSection("system.web/globalization");

OpenWebConfiguration("/"); // Point to Physical path for the Web.Config file (Useful when using Routing).

GetSection("system.web/globalization"); // Get the globalization section within the system.web node.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [`GlobalizationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection.aspx), so you can get at it via

```
var globalizationSection = 
        WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("globalization") as GlobalizationSection;
```

Comment: I tired with debugger and I get globalizationSection = null ... any ideas?

Comment: @GibboK - can you add the code that you are using for this to your question?

Comment: i'm using your code. var globalizationSection = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("globalization") as GlobalizationSection;

Comment: in web.config <system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto:fr" uiCulture="fr"/>

Comment: @GibboK - please add the complete relevant code you are using. Are you referencing `System.Configuration` assembly in the project? Does you code compile?

Comment: I did but it still give me null. My scenario is, web.config in root for my website and physical file with your code in a folder. Now I'm using Asp.Net Routing to visit the page in the folder ex: /mypage.aspx but mapping the url in the root ex: /mypage. I suppose the Routing create some problem and I'm not able to apply globalization on the page. Could be possible? Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What happens if you simply use `WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("globalization")`? Does that return a `ConfigurationSection` instance? I don't fully understand your description and it would be better explained by showing your code in the question. When you use `WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("globalization")`, it looks for the configuration that has been loaded for the current App Domain.

Comment: now is working. Problem was my globalization node was inside system.web GetSection("system.web/globalization"); Glad to accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

You might need to import the System.Configuration and System.Web.Configuration namespaces to do this, but you can do something like this:

```
//and here is the code to get the section
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");     
GlobalizationSection section = config.GetSection("globalization") as GlobalizationSection;
```

Comment: Cannot get Configuration DataType using the namespace using System.Web.Configuration; ... what I'm missing. thanks

Comment: @GibboK: Try importing System.Configuration too.

Comment: I try too but the problem persist, please read my comment to Russ Cam, I still have a strange problem with this. Thanks.

Comment: @GibboK: Add System.Configuration as a reference to the project, and then import System.Configuration and System.Web.Configuration on the page you need it.

Comment: Try - var globalizationSection = 
    config.GetSection("system.web/globalization") as GlobalizationSection;

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection.aspx

It looks like you need to include/use `System.Web.Configuration.GlobalizationSection`

Then .Culture
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection.culture.aspx#Y300